# Apply embedding layer for categorical variable with keras

Tags: python, keras, categorical-data, word-embedding, python-embedding

I have a dataset with many categorical features and many features.I want to apply embedding layer to transfer the categorical data to numerical data for the using of the other models.But, I got some error during training.
Now, my training process is:

1. Perform label encoder to categorical features
2. Split training and testing data by train_test_split() function
3. Drop the numerical columns. Only send the categorical features and target y for model training.

And I got this error:

```
    indices[13,0] = 10 is not in [0, 10)
     [[node functional_1/embed_6/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-34-0b6b3ae455d0>:4) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3509]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node functional_1/embed_6/embedding_lookup:
 functional_1/embed_6/embedding_lookup/2395 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

After searching, someone says the problem is that the vocabulary_size parameter of embedding layer is wrong. Enlarge the vocabulary_size can solve this problem.
But in my case, I need to map the result back to original label.

For example, I have a categorical feature `['dog', 'cat', 'fish']`. After label encode, it become`[0,1,2]`. An embedding layer for this feature with 3 unique variable should output something like
`([-0.22748041], [-0.03832678], [-0.16490786])`.
Then I can replace the `['dog']` variable in original data as `-0.22748041`, replace `['cat']` variable as `-0.03832678`, and so on.
So, I can't change the vocabulary_size or the output dimension will be wrong.

I guess the problem in my case is that not all of the categorical variable are go into the training process.
(E.x. Only `['dog', 'fish']` are in the training data. `['cat']` is only appear in testing data). If I set the vocabulary_size as 3, it will report an error like above. If I experimentally add `['cat']` to training data. It works fine.

My problem is, dose embedding layer have to look all of the unique value in training process to perform the application I want? If there are a lot of categorical data with a lot of unique value, how to ensure all the unique value appear in testing data when splitting data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You need to use **out-of-vocabulary** buckets when creating the the lookup table.
*oov* buckets allow to lookup of unknown category if found during testing.

## What the solution does?

Setting it to a required number (like 1000) will allow you to get ids of those other category as well which were not present in test data categories.

```py
words = tf.constant(vocabulary)
word_ids = tf.range(len(vocabulary), dtype=tf.int64)

# important
vocab_init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(words, word_ids)
num_oov_buckets = 1000
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(vocab_init, num_oov_buckets) # lokup table for ids->category
```

**Then you can encode the training set (I am using TensorFlow Dataset IMDb rating dataset)**

```py
def encode_words(X_batch, y_batch):
  """
  Encode the training set converting words to IDs
  using the lookup table just created
  """
  return table.lookup(X_batch), y_batch

train_set = datasets["train"].batch(32).map(preprocess)
train_set = train_set.map(encode_words).prefetch(1)
```

when creating model:

```py
vocab_size=10000    # whatever the length of variable vocabulary is of
embedding_size = 128  # tweakable | hyperparameter
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size + num_oov_buckets, embedding_size, 
                           input_shape=[None]),
   # usual code follows
])
```

and fit the data

```py
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics="accuracy")
history = model.fit(train_set, epochs=5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't understand the relationship between these two codes. `num_oov_buckets`  is the only variable in code block1 which also be used in block2. It seem like I should set the total unique value (including training set and testing set) number as the first parameter of Embedding layer. But I still got the same error. I can't figure out why block1 code can help block2 code run properly. Because `num_oov_buckets` is just and int variable. Would you mind to illustrate the code more? Thanks a lot !! How should I set the `num_oov_buckets`  and `vocab_size variable`?

Comment: Sorry It was mistake. The answer is updated. You need to encode the training set which will return the IDs of the categories (here vocabulary/words).

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with imdb dataset. The dataset loaded by tf seem to be a `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)` format. I am not sure what format and content should I put in the `datasets["train"]` variable. Would you mind to give me a little more hint or a simple demo start from loading data?

Comment: Don't mind. What I want to give the idea is it's important to give some space when creating the lookup table for categories not found in the training set. This is **oov buckets**. So the next argument table in `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(vocab_init, num_oov_buckets)`specify this. You can then look in documentation and tutorial how to do this on your dataset. As you didn't even provided that. And we can't really solve eveything, just give fix for guide you :)